# Enabling core files on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6, ulimit, sysctl, core-file

I am trying to enable core files on a machine running CentOS; however, nothing I have tried has produced core files…here is what I have done:

Added the following two lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*     hard    core    unlimited
*     soft    core    unlimited
```

Added the following line to `/etc/sysconfig/init`:

```
DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT='unlimited
```

Added the following line to `/etc/profile`:

```
ulimit -c unlimited > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Added the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.core_pattern = '/srv/core/%p_%t.core'
fs.suid_dumpable = 1
```

I made sure that `/srv/core` exists and has `777` permissions. The I executed `init 6` to reboot the OS. Upon the system coming back up, I executed the following C script in an attempt to produce a core file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  kill(getpid(), SIGQUIT);
}
```

The output is simply `Quit`, while I was hoping to see `Quit (core dumped)`; and it obviously does not produce a core file :(

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if core files are generated by default on CentOS 6, but handled by the "ABRT" service, which may write them into the `/var/spool/abrt` directory by default.  This is how a VM install works for me, at any rate. To illustrate this, I did the following:

1. "sleep 50 &"
2. "kill -SIGSEGV "
3. "abrt-cli list"
4. identify the "Directory:" line matching my segfaulted sleep process and cd to it
5. found the coredump file stored there

SIGQUIT seems to generate a core, as well.

Given these, I'd verify that the abrt services are running, I'd see whether I had previous entries in `/var/spool/abrt` that are masking out new core files (I think `abrt` tries to avoid duplicate entries, which you may want).  I'm not sure whether any additional configuration will help or hurt, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just change: 

kernel.core_pattern = '/srv/core/%p_%t.core' 
to 
kernel.core_pattern = /srv/core/%p_%t.core

without "'" and it will work...
```

Comment: I'll take your word on that...I'm 2 1/2 years past dealing with this (and have no clue at this point what I did to get it working or if I even did) - haha